# Slide puzzle app, DFS

Tags: c

I have following problem with solving sliding puzzle. I am in state, where I can determine if puzzle is solvable or not. And I have already created functions to move empty title to the left, right, up and down, they return 2D array if movement is possible or 0 if not. I store initial configuration in 2D array.

I choosed limited DFS to solve this problem. So I need to create something like tree (or linked list) struct where my initial configuration would be root. Then it'll have (2,3 or 4) childs depending on the position of zero. These nodes will contain int **array (returned by functions: *toLeft, toRight, toUp and toDown*) with next configuration.

So I can use recursion to create next nodes until there is goal configuration. Then I could "go" back to the root and print out the steps. So for example:
[5] LEFT
[7] UP
...
END

But I have problem with creating linked list. So far I have only:

```
typedef struct Node{
int **array;
struct Node *left;
struct Node *right;
struct Node *up;
struct Node *down;
}Node;
```

How can I add node into list and how can I determine if is it left, right, up, down?
Thank you.

**EDIT**

So on advice (which was deleted) I edited my code and added new functions...

```
   typedef struct Node{
    int **array;
    struct Node *left;
    struct Node *right;
    struct Node *up;
    struct Node *down;
    struct Node *parent;
    }Node;

Node* newNode(Node *parent, int **array){
    Node* u;
    u = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (u == NULL){
    printf("OUT OF MEMORY!");
    /* Free memory here.*/
    exit(1);
    }
    u->array = array;
    u->down = NULL;
    u->right = NULL;
    u->up = NULL;
    u->left = NULL;
    u->parent = parent;
    return u;
}

void setLeftNode(Uzel *parent, Uzel *child) {
  parent->left = child;
    }
/* setRightNode,Up,Down...*/


int isLeftChild (Node *node){
    if (node->parent == null) {return 0;}
    else{
        if (node->parent->left == node){return 1;}
        else{return 0;}
    }
}
/*is Right,Up,Down...*/
```

And I added root:
    Node* root = newNode(NULL, array);

So my questions are:
 1. How can I create another nodes (using recursion, and array(changed puzzle config) from their parents)?
 2. How will I call setLeftNode, setRightNode, etc.?

Thank you for your time. :)

Comment: I have edited post... with new piece of my code. But I am stuck. Also when I create a Node root.. and then I try to create Node n = newNode(root, array); it cause that my program terminate after launching it without any errors but it does nothing.

Comment: I edited it again and now, newNode works... I hope.

Comment: Are you sure you need the tree? Why not just use a stack of array states? (ie expand each possible next state and push it on to a stack, then pop one off, expand etc until you run out or the puzzle is solved)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Spudd86. You don't need to explicitly build the tree of state arrays. It's enough to only have the ones in the current path, and those can be keet in pointers on the stack.

Something roughly like this should work:

```
int dfs(int **state, int depthLimit, const char **steps) {
    if (isFinalState(state))
        return 1;

    if (depthLimit <= 0)
        return 0;

    int *newState;

    if (tryMoveLeft(state, &newState)) {
        if (dfs(newState, depthLimit, steps + 1)) {
            steps[0] = "left";
            freeState(newState);
            return 1;
        } else {
            freeState(newState);
        }
    }

    // The same for right, up, down ...

    // If no of the previous returns was taken, then this branch isn't the right one
    return 0;
}
```

`isFinalState()` should return if the state corresponds to a solved puzzle, `tryMoveLeft()` should return if moving left is valid and return a newly allocated state if it is and `freeState()` should free the state array.
Output will be stored in the array steps, which has to be allocated to enough size before the search is started.

This doesn't answer exactly what you asked, but I hope it helps anyway :-D

Comment: I have implemented algorithm with pseudocode written here:
http://www.docstoc.com/docs/28438033/The-8-Puzzle
But, I have still problem with infinte loops. Is there any formula for value of const DEPTHBOUND (limit of DFS) depending on size of puzzle? Thank you.

Comment: Well, I don't know about any formula for this. There will definitely be less than (n * n)! steps for puzzle with n*n fields, but that value is too large and it won't help you. If I remember correctly from school, then you should use the limited dfs by starting with limit 0 and then increasing the limit by one until you find a valid solution.